# Two different values for the Directional Derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was doing a question in physics and I needed to got the directional derivative in one point to two different vectors that make the same plane. But I got 2 different vallues for the derivative. The question is: Is it mean directly that the function isn't differentiable in that point? And if yes, how can I argue it reasonably consistently?

The function is:

$\phi(x, y)=-\lambda k ln(x^2 + y^2)$

And the vectors was: $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$

The point is $(2,2,2)$

Comment: What do you mean by two different vectors that make the same plane?

Comment: The whole point of a *directional* derivative is that a differentiable function usually changes faster in some directions than in others. For example, the function $f(x,y,z) = 100y$ changes rapidly in the $y$ direction but doesn't change at all in the $x$ or $z$ directions. Did you really expect a directional derivative to have the same value in every direction? Why?

Comment: Your example is a little unclear: you have a function of only two variables, but you have vectors with three components.